# Using Latexdiff math-markup for not comparing equations

Tags: equations, comparison, latexdiff

I am using Latexdiff to compare 2 Latex files.
I can do it successfully for text but it gives me problem with equations which I have a lot.

I do not want to compare the equations.
If I understand correctly, I can use an option

```
--math-markup=0
```

to exclude math environments from being compared.
I am using align and $$ environments for Maths but Latexdiff still goes to
check the math environment as I can see in the diff file that it produces.

I tried also [is there an option in latexdiff to ignore whole environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73224/is-there-an-option-in-latexdiff-to-ignore-whole-environments) and [Can latexdiff be used for mathematics documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/can-latexdiff-be-used-for-mathematics-documents) without success.

But I am more interested in trying math-markup option. 
What is going wrong?

Comment: remember `$$` is a tex primitive facility, not an environment.  the latex equivalent is `\[` with `\]` (it's a good rule of thumb _never_ to use `$$` in latex).  whether this helps with `latexdiff` i couldn't say.

Comment: Please add example code showing a case where this does not work.